# SlidingMenu Android Sporadic Issue

Tags: android, xml, slidingmenu

### Background Information

I am developing an Android app that uses [jmeinstein's Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). Because I needed to extend a SlidingListActivity, I decided to follow [baruckis Android SlidingMenuImplementation](https://github.com/baruckis/Android-SlidingMenuImplementation), using classes such as `SlidingMenuBuilderBase`, `SlidingMenuListAdapter`, etc. The issue I am having though is that the menu appears to be slightly off the page. However, the most interesting part about this problem is that it happens sometimes.

### The Issue

I have uploaded a private YouTube video to show you what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eYlqRl6F3k&feature=youtu.be

As you saw from the video, both pages (All Events and My Events) had the issue where the first menu item was slightly cut off. However, randomly, My Events started to properly correct the menu, and eventually, All Events did too. But I can't seem to figure out a pattern about why this is happening.

Just to be absolutely clear, I posted images of the error (which I see sometimes) and the correct image (which I also see sometimes):

[image: The Issue]
[image: What I Want]

### The Code

Now, for the code. Like I said, my code differs from jfeinstein's direct implementation of it and I follow baruckis' implementation, which is supposed to work correctly as demonstrated by baruckis' sample application.

```
private void createSlidingMenu(Session session) {
        // If nothing is set, than sliding menu wont be created.
        if (setSlidingMenu() != null) {
            Class<?> builder = setSlidingMenu();
            try {
                // We use our made base builder to create a sliding menu.
                slidingMenuBuilderBase = (SlidingMenuBuilderBase) builder
                        .newInstance();
                slidingMenuBuilderBase.createSlidingMenu(this, session, userName, userId);
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is called from the opening of the home page. Now, here is the create sliding menu:

```
public void createSlidingMenu(Activity activity, Session session, String userName, String userId) {
    this.activity = activity;
    // For actual sliding menu creation we use an external open source
    // Android library called "SlidingMenu". It can be found at
    // "https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu".
    // We configure the SlidingMenu to our needs.
    menu = new SlidingMenu(activity);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setAboveOffset(R.dimen.above_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
    this.session = session;
    this.userName = userName;
    System.out.println(userName);
    SlidingMenuListFragment slidingMenuListFragment = new SlidingMenuListFragment(userName, userId);
    slidingMenuListFragment.setMenuBuilder(this);
    // We replace a FrameLayout, which is a content of sliding menu, with
    // created list fragment filled with data from menu builder.
        activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame, slidingMenuListFragment)
        .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Other important samples of code:

SlidingMenuListFragment.java:

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    
        // We get a list from our specially created list data class.
        slidingMenuList = SlidingMenuList.getSlidingMenu(getActivity(), userName);
        // We pass our taken list to the adapter.
        SlidingMenuListAdapter adapter = new SlidingMenuListAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.sliding_menu_holo_light_list_row, slidingMenuList, userId);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

sliding_menu_holo_light_list.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6F0B0B"
    android:divider="#c0c0c0"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip" />
```

sliding_menu_holo_light_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
        android:padding="10dp" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/empty_string"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have been trying to solve this for days. All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just an FYI, the fact that your youtube video is private means that no one can view it, so we can't see the problem in action. Also, I know this doesn't answer your question, but you may want to consider switching to the [Google nav drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), as jfeinstein's sliding menu project is no longer being maintained or updated.

Comment: Ok, I changed the privacy settings. And okay, I will consider switching.